# Why do we need to use __new__() when extending a immutable class in Python?

Tags: python

I am reading the book **Mastering Object-Oriented Python**. In the part of book where it talks about the `__new__` method and immutable objects, it says something like the `__new__()` method is used to extend the immutable classes where the `__init__()` method can't easily be overridden. It also gives an example as below

```
class Float_Fail(float):
    def __init__(self, value, unit):
        super().__init__(value)
        self.unit = unit

f = Float_Fail(6.5, "knots")

TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-9511e6ca03be> in <module>()
----> 1 f = Float_Fail(6.5, "knots")
TypeError: float() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

I'm just curious why float gives this error. I mean, we can initialize a float like this:

```
f = float(1.1)
```

Doesn't it mean the `__init__()` method of `float` class takes the number as it's second argument. If not, how is the initialization of an immutable class implemented in Python?

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization) on `__new__` and `__init__`?  Hint: `__new__` is called *before* `__init__`.

Comment: I know __new__ is called before __init__, my question is when we initialize a float like this, f = float(1.1), in which method does the value 1.1 passed to the float object if not in the __init__ method?

Comment: `__new__`.  Because `__new__` is called **before** `__init__`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do `MyClass(1)`, then `1` is indeed passed as an argument to `__init__`.  But `__new__` is called before `__init__`, so `1` is *first* passed as an argument to `__new__`.  The error you are seeing is because you didn't override `__new__`, so the inherited `float.__new__` is being called, and it doesn't accept your extra argument.  It never gets a chance to even try calling `__init__`, because it fails when trying to call `__new__`.

This is explained in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization).  As clearly stated there, the arguments you pass when instiating a class (e.g., the `1` in `MyClass(1)`) are passed to *both* `__new__` *and* `__init__`, in that order.

Comment: Ok, that make sense. But I have a new question. If we can initialize a float object using float(1.1), does that mean the original __new__ method takes an extra argument? Obviously it doesn't. I'm curious how in this case, the value 1.1 is used in float initialization?

Comment: @Brian: I don't understand what you mean by "an extra argument".  "Extra" beyond what?

Comment: The \__new__() method of the float class only takes a single parameter called type, why there isn't a parameter which corresponds to 1.1 in the example, float(1.1)?

Comment: in python3 interactive session,>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getargspec(float.__new__)
ArgSpec(args=['type'], varargs='args', keywords='kwargs', defaults=None)
>>> inspect.getargspec(float.__init__)
ArgSpec(args=['self'], varargs='args', keywords='kwargs', defaults=None)

Comment: @Brian: Ah, I see.  That signature is misleading, though.  Note that it also accepts varargs and kwargs.  If you look at `float.__new__.__doc__`, you'll see that it tells you to look at the docs for the type (i.e., `help(float)`) to see the real signature, and `help(float)` shows that it accepts an argument for the value.

Answer (score 0):

By the time the `__init__` method runs, the object already exists. Since the object is immutable, its value can't be changed in `__init__`.